# Probability of palindrome of length 11

Tags: combinatorics, palindrome

What is the probability that a random bit string of length 11 is a palindrome?

Anyone have an idea of how to do this? I'm not sure how to calculate the different cases.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: you need $b_i = b_{12-i}$ for $i = 1$ to $5$.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2048 arbitrary bit strings of length 11.  Now count the pallindromic ones.  (How many can you choose arbitarily so the rest is determined?)

Comment: It would be clearer to ask "How many *bits* can you  choose...".

Comment: C'est vrai, Austin, but I am trying to offer the gentlest possible hint.

Answer (score 0):

the first 6 bits don't matter, as stated earlier b1 = b11 etc
Pallidromic=1/2 * 1/2 * 1/2 * 1/2 * 1/2